# Apache web server is not working in browser

Tags: apache, webserver

I recently installed Apache web server in my machine. I checked whether the server was running or not by using

```
`[root@localhost httpd-2.4.7]# /etc/init.d/httpd stop
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
[root@localhost httpd-2.4.7]# /etc/init.d/httpd start
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
[root@localhost httpd-2.4.7]# `
```

It is fine up to this.

My question is when I try to load a server page in the browser by using 
`http://localhost:8080` it's showing the error `This webpage is not available`.
 What is wrong?

Comment: Apache is configured on 8080 port? Maybe default on 80?

Comment: how to check that port? this is my httpd status `[root@localhost Admin]# service httpd status
httpd (pid  8501) is running...
`

Comment: show configuration: `cat /etc/apache2/ports.conf` and then `netstat -plnt | grep ':80'` and find apache2 service

Comment: `[root@localhost httpd-2.4.7]# netstat -plnt | grep ':80'
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      8501/httpd `

Comment: You must run: `http://localhost/`

Comment: OK, a will add that as ansewer and you will set as best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check port for apache:

```
netstat -plnt | grep ':80'
```

and if port will be `80` run:

```
http://localhost/
```

Comment: can you tell me how to run Perl CGI script using the Apache web server

Comment: cgi - is old days approach, better run perl scripts though mod_perl2 apache module

Comment: the correct way of checking apache bound port: `netstat -ntpl | grep httpd`  this command will show what port is used by httpd.

Comment: can you tell me how to install that mod_perl2 apache module ? pls pls

Answer (score 0):

first go to in configure httpd.conf folder in apache and open change the port value 80 instead of 8080 ( two place u need to check in code  )  .

then go to services (click ur  start button and type this in " search programs  and file ") and then search for  "Web Deployment Agent Service"and stop it. then go and restart ur apache. then ur local host will start work .

if not then after stop "Web Deployment Agent Service" in services , again open httpd.conf folder in apache  and edit 8080 instead of 80( two place u need to check in code  ) . hope this will  work.

Answer (score -1):

I hope it will help full to u
I think you need to change tomcat port number because for example oracle  default port number is 8080,anyway do one thing go to ur tomcat home directory in conf folder open server.xml file you find below this tag u find portno=8080 ...change this to 2014 or somethig and save it same folder.restart u r server and give this url `http://localhost:2014`

Comment: there is no conf foder

Comment: search for server.xml in tomcat folder using search option

Comment: this is httpd not tomcat